# How can I add SSL capabilities in twisted portforward proxy

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following code for a portforward proxy. How can I add
ssl support so that the proxy can connect to a server listening with ssl.

here is the code:

```
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    from twisted.protocols import portforward

    class ProxyServer(portforward.ProxyServer):
        def dataReceived(self, data)
        portforward.ProxyServer.dataReceived(self, data)

    class ProxyFactory(portforward.ProxyFactory):
        protocol = ProxyServer


        reactor.listenTCP(8080,ProxyFactory("127.0.0.1",443) )
        reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out. This excerpt is probably relevant to what you are looking for . 
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/ssl.html

```
with open('server.pem') as keyAndCert:
    cert = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(keyAndCert.read())

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = echoserv.Echo
reactor.listenSSL(8000, factory, cert.options())
reactor.run()
```

"Notice how all of the protocol code from the TCP version of the echo client and server examples is the same (imported or repeated) in these SSL versions - only the reactor method used to initiate a network action is different."